# magento2.4.3-p1. back end. Select customer and View Orders. An error message appears

Tags: orders, backend, magento2.4.3, error-log, magento2.4.3.p1

A Message is displayed : "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

Have you experienced this ? Can it be fixed ?

Comment: Did you check the logs? Do a: tail -f var/log/* from inside your Magento installation, then check if any errors pop up in the logs after you select a customer

Comment: yes. Undefined Property $_collectionFactory

in /home/MyStore/public_html/app/code/MyStore/Mystore/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/Orders.php

Comment: paste that file content